# Delete Double PSObjects from Array

Tags: powershell

I'm reading out all my Computers from my two Domain Controllers. To get a list of all computers which were Online in between the last 50 days.

Some of the Computers will be listed in both variables. How can I delete/ignore the double entries so I get each Object only once?

`sort -unique` only returns one single PSObject

```
# Computer von DC1 auslesen
$DC1 = Invoke-Command -Session $BBDC1 {
    Get-Adcomputer -filter * -property * | ? { $_.LastLogonDate -gt ((Get-Date).adddays("-50")) } |
    Select CN, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate | Sort CN
}

# Computer von DC2 auslesen
$DC2 = Invoke-Command -Session $BBDC2 {
    Get-Adcomputer -filter * -property * | ? { $_.LastLogonDate -gt ((Get-Date).adddays("-50")) } |
    Select CN, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate | Sort CN
}

$computers = $DC1 + $DC2 | sort -Unique
```

Comment: Domain Controllers replicate computer objects between them?  You're reading the PowerShell provided formatted value of lastlogontimestamp which is the computer object property that is replicated between DCs already so this shouldn't be a concern about finding the most up-to-date one?

Comment: I guess the better question is, what is it you are trying to achieve?  The reason your sort is acting funny is because complex objects are being returned and it doesn't doesn't sort on the entire object.  you have to identify a specific property to sort -unique on:  sort -unique property lastlogontimestamp

Answer (score 0):

Use the -Property

`Sort-Object -Property CN, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate -Unique`

But if the LastLogonDate is different, then this doesn't work.